# How does IIS register/find the DLLs in the /bin folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, web-config

I have a static HTML website running under IIS.  I need to have one path that does something executable (sends an email).  I figured I'd write a simple handler.

I have configured my web.config with this:

```
<add name="Emailer" verb="*" path="sendemail" type="Emailer, Emailer.dll" />
```

Then I wrote an HttpHandler and compiled to a DLL called Emailer.dll.

Then I naively just created a `/bin` folder in the root and dropped my DLL into it.

I get the error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Emailers.dll' or one of its dependencies.
```

So, IIS sees my handler registration and dutifully attempts to find it, but it's "blind" to the DLL in the `/bin` folder I created.

So, what makes the `/bin` folder...magic?  I just created a folder at the root of the website, assuming whatever was in it would be visible to IIS.  Evidently, I was wrong.

How do I get IIS to look in a folder I created for assemblies?

(Note that this was not an ASP.Net website originally.  Normally, when writing an ASP.Net website, I start from Visual Studio, which I'm assuming bootstraps a lot of stuff with web.config settings.  But this was an empty IIS site to which I just added a "web.config" and "/bin" folder.)

Comment: Did you try making the website an application (I think it's "convert to application" in the IIS console)?

Comment: I could only "Add application..." so I added one in a folder at the root and moved all my stuff into it.  Same error.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your current layout, both in the IIS console and in the filesystem, so we can get a better picture of what's up

Comment: I figured it out. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem is that you don't need the "dll" in the handler element. Just "Emailer." It adds the "dll" automatically.